# Laurent Series Expansion for $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am having trouble with Laurent series expansions. I am supposed to find the Laurent Series Expansion for $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ around $0<|z| < \infty$. I know the definitions of $a_n$ and $b_n$ for the Laurent expansion but that is all. Is there another way of arriving at the same, without using the definition?

Comment: Hint: Do you know a series representation of $\sin w$ that converges whenever $w\neq\infty$? What happens, if you substitute $w=1/z$ there? For which choice of $z$ will the resulting series converge?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We know that $sin(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} (-1)^{n+1}$. If we substitute we would get it converging for any z not equal to 0.

Comment: So, what problem remains?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Close as dupe?